# Can secret recipients be included in PGP cryptography

Tags: cryptography, openpgp, public-key

Can we be sure that a cleartext message that becomes encrypted by pgp or openpgp which is intended for one-or-more specific recipients doesn't also get secretly decipherable by a third party? Since i understand we can target multiple recipients when ciphering, how do i know software isn't adding extra recipients for, like, shadow govt type stuff. If openpgp is open source, I'd think it would be known that it's not so private

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple subtle ways in which a program such as PGP could be backdoored. But assuming just the threat scenario of an additional recipient (such as the one you could add yourself with a `encrypt-to` setting on your gpg.conf) it's simple to verify.

First we should refresh how openpgp public key cryptography works:

- The openpgp client generates a random key, called "session key"
- This session key is encrypted for each of the recipients with their public key
- The message is encrypted with the session key using a symmetric algorithm
- The output of the last two steps is the resulting encrypted file

On decryption, the reverse steps are followed:

- The openpgp client iterates all the Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packets, looking for one tagged as being encrypted to the Key ID of your public key (any of them, if you have several ones).
- The client recovers the session key using the private key of the user
- The message is decrypted withe the session key

It is possible to use "hidden recipients". These are just recipients for which the Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packets don't include the recipient Key ID (a Key-ID of 0 is stored instead), so it's not obvious to who else is encrypted the message. In order to figure out if it is intended for its key, the client must attempt to decrypt it with each of its keys. But overall, it's not different to the normal case.

You can view the OpenPGP packets with either `pgpdump` or `gpg --list-packets`.

A normal encrypted file/message will contain one [Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1) per recipient plus a [Symmetrically Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.13) (a [Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.7) instead would be an option, but everything should support MDC nowadays).

By counting the number of Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packets included, you can know the number of recipients for a given file (even though you may not know *who* they are).

If you client added secret recipients, they would show up in the file having more Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packets than recipients.

(or if they replaced a recipient with the key of a third party, that would be detectable as well, as that recipient would be unable to decrypt it)

Please note that if you are including yourself so that you can decrypt the files, you are also considered a recipient (e.g. if you encrypt a file for Alice and Bob, and you have enabled the setting to encrypt to yourself, the total number of recipients is *three*)

Obviously, an inspection of the encrypted message should be done with a [trusted program](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/358198.358210), since a trojanized client that added a secret recipient could be skipping it when listing the recipients. The task can be easily performed on a different machine, though, and it's not too hard to perform that manually from an hex view, even.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of open source applications is that you can see for yourself that the program isn't doing something malicious. Kleopatra is a fantastic application for PGP encrypting your messages.

Answer (score 0):

First, PGP is opensource. You probably will not inspect the sourcecode, but someone will. The history of the changes are kept, so if the code had some backdoor at some time, it would be public that the backdoor was added and later removed. If you don't trust the distributed binary, you can (relatively) easily download the source and compile yourself.

Second, good crypto follows [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle): everything is known except the key. PGP does not uses any secret or hidden function. All the functions and methods used are public, they are on the source code.

PGP was created to make easy to people to use encryption, and Phil Zimmerman, his creator, [got in trouble with the government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Zimmermann) because of it. He is a known privacy advocate.